# Explore the differences between HTML.Partial and HTML.RenderPartial, as well as HTML.Action and HTML.RenderAction in ASP.NET MVC and Core

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

which is better to use

HTML.Partial and HTML.RenderPartial are methods for rendering partial views in ASP.NET MVC and Core. HTML.Partial returns HTML content as an MvcHtmlString, allowing further manipulation, while HTML.RenderPartial directly writes to the response stream for efficiency. On the other hand, HTML.Action and HTML.RenderAction invoke child action methods. HTML.Action returns a MvcHtmlString, useful for capturing and manipulating output, whereas HTML.RenderAction writes directly to the response stream. The choice depends on your need to capture output and performance requirements. HTML.RenderPartial and HTML.RenderAction are more efficient for direct rendering, while HTML.Partial and HTML.Action offer greater control and flexibility.

[Lemborco](https://forum.lemborco.com/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

When working with partial views and child actions in ASP.NET MVC and Core, it's essential to understand the differences between `HTML.Partial`, `HTML.RenderPartial`, `HTML.Action`, and `HTML.RenderAction` to make an informed choice based on your specific requirements.

1. **HTML.Partial:**

   - **Return Type:** MvcHtmlString
   - **Purpose:** Renders a partial view with content control.
   - **Recommended Use Cases:** Choose `HTML.Partial` when you need to capture and manipulate the output of a partial view before rendering it. This method provides you with control and flexibility over the rendered content. For example:

     ```
     @Html.Partial("_UserProfile", user)
     ```
2. **HTML.RenderPartial:**

   - **Return Type:** Writes to Response
   - **Purpose:** Renders a partial view efficiently.
   - **Recommended Use Cases:** Consider using `HTML.RenderPartial` when performance is a primary concern, and you don't require further manipulation of the output. This method efficiently renders a partial view without the need for additional control. For example:

     ```
     @Html.RenderPartial("_Sidebar")
     ```
3. **HTML.Action:**

   - **Return Type:** MvcHtmlString
   - **Purpose:** Invokes and captures the output of child action methods.
   - **Recommended Use Cases:** Utilize `HTML.Action` when you want to invoke a child action method and capture its output for further manipulation. This method allows you to control and modify the child action's output. For example:

     ```
     @Html.Action("RecentPosts", "Blog")
     ```
4. **HTML.RenderAction:**

   - **Return Type:** Writes to Response
   - **Purpose:** Invokes and renders child actions efficiently.
   - **Recommended Use Cases:** If you prioritize rendering efficiency for child actions and do not need to manipulate the output, choose `HTML.RenderAction`. It efficiently renders child actions without the need for additional control. For example:

     ```
     @Html.RenderAction("FeaturedItems", "Store")
     ```

The choice between these methods ultimately depends on your specific application needs. If you need control and flexibility over the output, opt for `HTML.Partial` or `HTML.Action`. If rendering efficiency is crucial and no further manipulation is required, consider `HTML.RenderPartial` or `HTML.RenderAction`.